# AVR [ Why IO Registers have IO addresses and SRAM Adresses ]

Tags: avr

I was checking ATMEGA16 datasheet , and at pg17 I found that there is the IO registers that happen to have " IO addresses and SRAM addresses " ,

I don't know which we use and why there is two kinds of addressing for IOs ?

I need to know if it's part of the SRAM or not , Please enlight me ^^

[Page 17 Data address space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIQYz.png)

Comment: Better asked @ http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Registers are not in SRAM. This question is more about MCU architecture than programming. Study how data buses work. That will explain why the registers and RAM use an overlapping address space.

Comment: @UncleO I think you misundersood the question. On the AVR-Architecture some part of the register file is visible in both - the IO **and** the Memory-Addressspace.

Answer (score 1):

you can adress the registers using the normal/generic memory opcodes (by using it SRAM address) or you can access some of the registers using the faster io op codes that also allow you a faster bit level access. In the latter case you have to use the IO address.

Usually you want to to use the IO adresses and the opcodes. But the SRAM-Adresses enables you to pass register targets as data pointers to functions.

Usually your C-Compiler manages this for you and you never have to think about it.